# controllers integration test grails3: services are not getting injected

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-3.0

I am upgrading a grails app from 2.4.3 to 3.0.8. 
There are a lot of integration tests which are using `grails.util.GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest(grailsApplication.mainContext)` following by `controller.method` call. But I discovered that `grails.util.GrailsWebUtil` doesn't contain `bindMockWebRequest` method anymore, seems like it has been replaced with `grails.util.GrailsWebMockUtil`, alright, but all services declared in controller are **not getting injected into the class**. I could use `grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec`  but this class has also been removed from grails3.  There is a [suggestion](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/testing.html#functionalTesting) to use functional tests for integration test of controllers, but this solution doesn't work for me, I'm not itching to implement all these tests as functional, or inject dependencies manually into controller instances, how can I fix it?

Comment: `ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = (ConfigurableApplicationContext)grailsApplication.getMainContext();
        ctx.getBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(controller,
                AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME, false);` - could be a solution

Comment: Here's a complete example of how to write integration tests for controller with grails 3 http://nimavat.me/blog/grails3-controller-integration-test-example

Comment: @SudhirN Link to your blog no longer works

Answer (score 0):

Use `grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration` annotation instead of `grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec` class extension.

And move the integration tests to `src/integration-test/groovy`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm upgrading from Grails 2.5.1 to 3.2.4. One of my integration tests could not find the service I injected with def xxxService. I included the service in the @Mock list. XxxServiceIntegrationSpec extends Specification.

I know this does not quite relate to testing controllers, but maybe it helps?

Answer (score 0):

We had dozones of controller integration in our old grails 2.x app. When we migrated to grails 3, we wanted to keep it, can not throw them and write functional tests from scratch.

Here I have blogged about it [Integration testing controllers with Grails 3](http://nimavat.me/blog/grails3-controller-integration-test-example)

The basic steps are
- setup mock request and response
- set current controller name
- rest mock request and response at the end of the test

See the above blog post for a complete example.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a solution to this (I had the same problem), I found this example really useful:
https://github.com/albertodeavila/testingGrails3

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.